# php mysql_query related queries

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to run a query to a table in my database and the `id` field of the row that returns me to run a query to get the `assistance` field of a different table.

The code I'm trying to do is for a webService, my idea is to brand all fields of the first consultation separated by `;` but the `assistance` of the second table, and separate each row returned by field `:`

I just started programming in php, so I apologize if I did not express myself well or ask very basic things.

Thanks for your time and help.

**CODE**

```
if($tabla =="servicio")
    {
        $consulta = "SELECT `tipo` , `nombre` , `descripcion` , `hora` , `minuto` ,`lugar` , `duracion`,`fecha` , `horacero`, `id` FROM `".$tabla;

        $resultado= mysql_query($consulta,$enlace);


        $arraySalida = array();
        while($registro = mysql_fetch_assoc ($resultado) ):

             $consulta2 = "SELECT `asistencia` FROM `voluntarioServicio` WHERE id = `".$registro['id']."` AND emei = '".$emei."' ";
             $resultado2= mysql_query($consulta,$enlace);
                        $registro2 = mysql_fetch_assoc ($resultado2);
             $cadena = "{$registro['tipo']};{$registro['nombre']};{$registro['descripcion']};{$registro['hora']};{$registro['minuto']};{$registro['lugar']};{$registro['duracion']};{$registro['fecha']};{$registro['horacero']};{$registro2['asistencia']}";
             $arraySalida[]= $cadena;

        endwhile;

    echo implode(":",$arraySalida); 
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Note that you are missing the closing backtick on your table name and the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. By the way, returning something like a json structure would make processing and parsing a lot easier.

Comment: @jeroen if true mysql_ * are obsolete but the hosting that I use still holds, has a very old version of php. The problem is that the array output query fields appear to me but in the space dedicated to the field "assistance" of consultation2 is empty.

If you do not mind I edit the post to put the problem two is that query "returns an empty string

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of quotes in your sql: `... WHERE id = '".$registro['id']."' AND ...`. And you should probably use a JOIN instead of querying the database in your loop.

Comment: @jeroen you are right, use a JOIN is the solution. I've write the code down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better SQL is

```
$consulta = "SELECT `table_a`.*, `table_b`.`asistencia`
    FROM `".$tabla."` `table_a`
        JOIN `voluntarioServicio` `table_b` ON `table_a`.`id` = `table_b`.`id`;";
```

because you get everything from inner select

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I have already solved. I leave here the code, I hope someone will serve.

**CODE**

```
        $consulta = "SELECT tipo,nombre,descripcion,hora,minuto,lugar,duracion,fecha,horacero,id,asistencia FROM ( SELECT ".$tabla.".*, voluntarioServicio.asistencia  FROM ".$tabla."left join voluntarioServicio on (".$tabla.".id=voluntarioServicio.id) ) as tabla";
            $resultado= mysql_query($consulta,$enlace);
            $arraySalida = array();
            while($registro = mysql_fetch_assoc ($resultado) ):

                     $cadena = "{$registro['tipo']};{$registro['nombre']};{$registro['descripcion']};{$registro['hora']};{$registro['minuto']};{$registro['lugar']};{$registro['duracion']};{$registro['fecha']};{$registro['horacero']};{$registro['asistencia']}";
                     $arraySalida[]= $cadena;
            endwhile;

            echo implode(":",$arraySalida);
```